# Select containing row based on CSS and content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I know how to deal with CSS, so I could create custom filter to block some post's name from some websites with a chrome extension called "stylish".

However, as CSS3 selector not allow to search inverted way, I want to enhance my custom filter using Tampermonkey in Chrome with jQuery or javascript.

What I want is an effect like below with javascript (which doesn't work with CSS3 yet.)

```
.wordbreak[content="USER_NAME"] < a < tr {display:none!important}
```

What I meant to do is; find classes named `wordbreak` also which contains the text 'USER_NAME' for the first, and then set their styles to "display:none" if the "tr" sibling tree is formed as; `tr > a > .wordbreak` + the inner text is "USER_NAME"

I've look through greasemonkey.org to find something like this one, but I couldn't any clue to how to make it work though. help would be grateful !

---

Link of [the page](https://cafe.naver.com/jssct?iframe_url=/ArticleList.nhn%3Fsearch.clubid=23134993%26search.boardtype=L) I want to modify

List of the posts and I want to hide the line of authored by "LibereQ: [image: HTML structure]

---

The first shot :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Black list
// @match        https://cafe.naver.com/MyCafeIntro*
// @match        https://cafe.naver.com/jssct*
// @match        https://cafe.naver.com/jssct
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelectorAll('tr > td > div > table > tbody > tr > td > a > .wordbreak').forEach(wordbreak => {
  if (wordbreak.textContent.includes('LiberaQ')) wordbreak.style.display = 'none';
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The Reddit example is redundant.  You should delete it from the question.  (Keep it as simple as possible.)

Comment: thanks @Brock Adams ! I'll keep in mind to make it clear as possible. I'm working on make it clear as much as I can :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That script has 3 main problems:

1. The target pages are AJAX (javascript) driven so you must use AJAX-aware techniques such as `MutationObserver` or `waitForKeyElements`.
2. The selector is overly complicated -- which means:
     (a) you must get it EXACTLY right and missing `td`s (for example) are deal-breakers
     (b) The script becomes much more brittle (likely to fail on some pages, or in the future).
3. The `@match` list is wrong.  The actual content you appear to be targeting is in an iframe with an address like: `cafe.naver.com/ArticleList.nhn?search...`.

The content you want is conveniently marked with a `wordbreak` class. That is the ideal selector by itself (based on what you've shown). Keep it simple.

Also keeping the `@match` simple, but you might be okay with the alternate.

Here's a complete script that illustrates the process:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Black list
// @match       https://cafe.naver.com/*
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

//Possible alternate match:
// @match       https://cafe.naver.com/ArticleList*

waitForKeyElements (".wordbreak", hideBlackListedNode);

function hideBlackListedNode (jNode) {
    if (jNode.text ().includes ('LiberaQ') ) {
        //jNode.hide ();                             // Hide just the node
        //jNode.closest ("tr").hide ();              // Hide the containing row
        /* Hide the containing row of the containing table
           The .parent() is needed due to a quirk of .closest().
        */
        jNode.closest ("tr").parent ().closest ("tr").hide ();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's work! however the one 'tr' that i want to hide is on outside of the 'tr' so I should found secondly closest 'tr' from the 'LiberaQ' I'll attach the screenshot of console and page

Comment: on the screen shot, it only hides LiberaQ's nick name, however I'd better remove the random screenshots from my posts.

Comment: Oops, forgot about a jQuery quirk. Try it now.

Comment: Woow, awesome, I don't know am I gonna able to modify quite freely, but I believe the someday will be come, Many thanks ! I'll keep look through your works to understand how it works !

Answer (score 1):

Select all `.wordbreak`s that match the selector string, and check their `textContent`. If it includes `USER_NAME`, set the element's `display` property:

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr > a > .wordbreak').forEach(wordbreak => {
  if (wordbreak.textContent.includes('USER_NAME')) {
    wordbreak.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

(But are you *sure* you have an `a` which is a direct descendant from a `tr`? If it's valid HTML you should see a `td` there instead, and probably use something more like `tr > td > a > .wordbreak`)

Comment: No, the siblings are just an example to make the explain to not to getting longer , a site that I want to make a blacklist is actually formed as like tr > td > a > span.wordbrek

Comment: I don't see `LiberaQ` anywhere on the site you mentioned. Please post the relevant HTML in your question itself rather than have answerers guess at it

Comment: however, I made a code like on the article on temper monkey, but it's not hiding the "LiberaQ" 's post name on this site on this site link ; cafe.naver.com/jssct and on the list of "전체글보기", It's probably my mistake that it's not work, but for me, the code is perfect and not reason to do not work. :0..?

Comment: Please see my above comment - post all relevant information in your question itself, including the HTML structure

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that you already posted your comment while i'm on editing my comment, I put the screen shot with console panel. hope that would be good enough find the clue.

Comment: however, the table is formed under `<iframe src="//cafe.naver.com/MyCafeIntro.nhn?clubid=23134993">` so that's way I put `@match        https://cafe.naver.com/MyCafeIntro*` just in case to cover the site properly, but still not working..

Comment: It might be that the `.wordbreak`s are being added to the HTML *after* the document loads, in which case the elements do not exist at the time the script runs. If that's the case, you might try using `setTimeout` to run the script after a small delay: `setTimeout(() => { document.querySelectorAll ... ... }, 1000);`. Or if that's not enough, maybe use MutationObserver to watch for changes, but that's complicated

Comment: Sorry about random non readable texts on the example URL, I'll just check whether the code is work or not work on other sites, if the the code is not only work on the site that I first mentioned, but work on another sites then it would be okay for me to make me by giving me allowance to modify lots of sites.
for just in case if you want to test the thing on your device, I left the picture of how to access the list on that I mentioned, by clicking the rew boxed text, you can access the list of the table. I'll test the code on reddit or some other sites thanks!

Comment: on the reddit, currently the best article is the username " u/rammerhammer95 ", so for the test, I replaced the url to reddit, contact text's name to 'u/rammerhammer95', and the selector to `document.querySelectorAll('div > div > a')` but nothing changed though. I guess I made violated the extension "TemperMonkey"s own rule, don't I?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake, `setProperty` is meant for `style` tags, not for `style` properties *on elements themselves*. Instead, set the style directly (ignoring `!important`): `<someElement>.style.display = 'none';` works for me when trying to remove the display of a particular user on reddit submissions.

Comment: I think I don't fully got what you meant as it's not work on me. would you check the code at the end of the post ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments and your time, even got an answer from @Brock Adams , but still the code you gave me would be help me out to how the script works ! thank you!